# how to set selected value from database into dropdown list

Tags: php, html

I am using dropdown list in my form. If the value already in the database, I want that value doesn't display in the dropdown list.

```
<select name="bank_name" id="bank_name" required>
   <option value="">Select Bank</option>
   <?php
      $query_val = mysql_query("SELECT  *  from bank order by bankname ");
      while($row_subject = mysql_fetch_array($query_val)) {
   ?>
   <option  value="<?php echo $row1["bank_name"];?>" <?php if(!empty($_POST['bank_name']) && $_POST['bank_name']==$row_subject['bankname']){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>
      <?php echo $row_subject['bankname'];?>
   </option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

How to display the stored value from database into dropdown list?

Answer (score -1):

Try this below . In select box option value you have defined the wrong value ($row1["bank_name"]) and query also not defined the orderby

```
<select name="bank_name" id="bank_name" required>

<option value="">Select Bank</option>
<?php

$query_val = mysql_query("SELECT  *  from bank order by bankname asc ");

while($row_subject = mysql_fetch_array($query_val)) {
?>
    <option  value="<?php echo $row_subject["bank_name"];?>" <?php if(!empty($_POST["bank_name"]) && $_POST["bank_name"]==$row_subject["bankname"]){echo 'selected="selected"';}?>>
    <?php echo $row_subject["bankname"];?>
    </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: The OP needs to avoid using the mysql_* series of functions which were ***REMOVED*** from PHP as of version 7.0 and instead use either the mysqli (MySQL Improved) functions or PDO